# In Magento's Test Automation Framework (TAF), what is the MCA part of a page URL?

Tags: php, magento

What is the meaning of the abbreviation MCA in the function [_getMcaFromCurrentUrl](https://github.com/magento/taf/blob/master/lib/Mage/Selenium/TestCase.php#L1377)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code MCA probably means *M*odule *C*ontroller *A*ction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Exactly it's *M*odule *C*ontroller *A*ction. that allow identify current page as it's unique.

Comment: Great to have this official answer by the Magento TAF team!